# Change last page URL

Tags: javascript, browser, back-button

I have 3 steps form, like this:

```
http://example.com/first-step
http://example.com/second-step
http://example.com/summary-step
```

I also have profile page:

```
http://example.com/profile
```

Requirement is that user cannot get back (using browser's `back` button) from `summary-step` to any of previous steps, he/she should be redirected to `profile` page.

This logic, for some reasons, unfortunely cannot be done on backend side, so only thing remaining is manipulating browser's history. In other words, if user reaches `summary-step`, previous page in browser history should be replaced from `second-step` to `profile`.

Is it doable? Important fact is that this should work not only on desktop, but also most popular mobile devices (iOS >= 7, Android, WP7+). Anchor hacks or adding `url's get` parameter is also impossible, as long as it hits backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can add your Profile page URL to the history using Javascript!

```
window.history.pushState('profile', null, '/profifeURL');
```

Comment: Yes, it helped. Thanks :)